# Can't get reference to existing window

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, same-origin-policy

I need to get a reference object to a window in Firefox which was not opened by the current page, but is of the same protocol, port and host. So complies with the same-origin policy.

I was using the code below to do this:

```
var mainWindow = window.open('', ''MAIN_WINDOW');
```

This was working before Firefox 52, however since the 52 update this code just opens a new blank tab, instead of referencing to the currently open window. I've looked at the fixes in the 52 release and I can't see anything which would have directly effected this.

Doing console.log(window.name) in the window I want reference to returns ' MAIN_WINDOW'. So The window name is correct.

I am then trying to access the frames array within the window reference later on in the code. Is there a way to solve this issue or an alternative I can try?

Comment: are you trying to open new window instead of tab or you are fine with the tab, but need to get a reference if that tab was already opened?

Comment: @Olga The second one. So the tab will already be open and I'm trying to get a reference to it

Comment: Please provide a sample code then how you create frames when it is new window and then accessing those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the windows are same-origin you can use a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) to let separate windows or tabs talk to each other